# Are route53 failover policy records only useful for non aws alias-able resources?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-route53

If all my endpoints are AWS services like ELB or S3 "Evaluate Target Health" can be used instead of failover records correct? I can use multiple weighted, geo, or latency records and if I enabled "Evaluate Target Health" it also servers the purpose of failover if one of the resources a record is pointing to is not healthly route53 will not send traffic to it.

The only use I see for failover records with custom healthchecks is for non-aws resources OR if maybe you have a more complex decision you want DNS to make instead of just ELB/S3/etc service health.

EDIT: so it seems while I can get active-active with "Evaluate Target Health" (on alias endpoints) if I want active-passive I have to use a failover policy- is this correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Essentially, yes.  Evaluating target health makes the records viable candidates for generating responses, only when healthy.  Without a failover policy, they're all viable when they're all healthy.

If you do something like latency-based routing and you had two targets, let's say Ohio and London, then you'd essentially have a dual active/passive configuration with reversed roles -- Ohio active and London passive for viewers in North America, and the roles reversed for viewers in Europe.  But if you want global active/passive, you'd need a a failover policy.

Note that if you are configuring any kind of high-availability design using Route 53 and target health, your best bet is to do all of this behind CloudFront -- where the viewer always connects to CloudFront and CloudFront does the DNS lookup against Route 53 to find the correct origin based on whatever rules you've created.  The reason for this is that CloudFront always respects the DNS TTL values.  Browsers, for performance reasons, do not.  Your viewers can find themselves stuck with DNS records for a dead target because their browsers don't flush their cached DNS lookups until all tabs in all windows are closed.  For users like me, that almost never happens.

This also works with latency-based routes in Route 53 behind CloudFront, because CloudFront has already routed the viewer to its optimal edge, and when that edge does a lookup on a latency-based route in Route 53, it receives the answer that has the lowest latency from the CloudFront edge that's handling the request... so both viewer to CloudFront and CloudFront to origin routes are thus optimal.

Note also that failover routing to S3 with only DNS is not  possible, because S3 expects the hostname to match the bucket name, and bucket names are global.  An S3 failure is a rare event, but it has happened at least once.  When it happened, the impact was limited to a single region, as designed.  For a site to survive an S3 regional failure requires additional heroics involving either CloudFront and Lambda@Edge triggers, or EC2-based proxies that can modify the request as needed and send it to the alternate bucket in an alternate region.

Latency-based routing to buckets with Route 53 is also not possible, for the same reason, but can be accomplished by Lambda@Edge origin request triggers.  These triggers are aware of the AWS region where a given invocation is running, and thus can swap origin servers based on location.

Comment: "dual active/passive" is an interesting way of describing it i had not thought of. with regards to dns client caching I think your describing the "long tail" issue right? Also, Cloudfront is considerably more $$$ when your doing a very high volume of bandwidth. I never see that mentioned but its a serious consideration when your pushing a lot of traffic.

Comment: Not really.  When you're using CloudFront, you aren't paying for bandwidth out of EC2 or S3 -- those charges are waived, and in some places CloudFront is slightly lower -- like us-east-2, $0.085/GB-out (CF) vs $0.090/GB-out (EC2/S3).

Comment: What if I have instances behind an ELB? does that change anything? Ill always have to pay ELB data processing costs, but do I pay data transfer out from ELB too? also it looks liek you also pay per http request with cloudfront so that another charge?

Comment: There is no charge for data transfer, out, from ELB to CloudFront.  ELB is part of EC2 and traffic from all of EC2 to CloudFront is $0.00/GB.  You'd only pay for the ELB data processing charge (classic) or LCU charge (ALB).

Comment: Yes, CloudFront has a small per-request charge, but remember that for content that is cached, none of the rest of your infrastructure sees that traffic at all.